# VSTS Release- SSH command 'Failed to create shell'

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops

I'm attempting to run some simple SSH commands on a remote linux server through Visual Studio Team Services' SSH release task.

Note that I have replaced the actual system path and folder name with REDACTED_PATH and REDACTED_FOLDER; these are fully qualified in the actual script/log.

When attempting to run the following

```
cd REDACTED_PATH
rm -rf REDACTED_FOLDER
```

Things error out completely, with the error `Failed to create shell`.

Has anyone had experience successfully using this? Am I missing something obvious?

I've tried this using both the Hosted Linux Preview agent and the Hosted VS2017 agent, with basically the same results. I'm able to connect using the same key from my laptop, and everything is happy.

Below is the error I'm seeing in context:

```
2018-04-06T20:31:55.0026263Z ##[debug]Using private key for ssh connection.
2018-04-06T20:31:55.0050569Z ##[debug]runOptions=commands
2018-04-06T20:31:55.0077685Z ##[debug]commands=cd REDACTED_PATH
2018-04-06T20:31:55.0097342Z rm -rf REDACTED_FOLDER
2018-04-06T20:31:55.0123717Z ##[debug]failOnStdErr=false
2018-04-06T20:31:55.0139035Z Trying to setup SSH connection to ********@site.ssh.SITE.com:22
2018-04-06T20:31:56.0144829Z Successfully connected.
2018-04-06T20:31:56.0174222Z ##[debug]Running command cd REDACTED_PATH on remote machine.
2018-04-06T20:31:56.0197149Z cd REDACTED_PATH
2018-04-06T20:31:56.0230068Z ##[debug]cmdToRun = cd REDACTED_PATH
2018-04-06T20:32:00.7153390Z ##[debug]code = 0, signal = undefined
2018-04-06T20:32:00.7186649Z ##[debug]Command cd REDACTED_PATH completed with return code = 0
2018-04-06T20:32:00.7218927Z ##[debug]Running command rm -rf REDACTED_FOLDER on remote machine.
2018-04-06T20:32:00.7238138Z rm -rf REDACTED_FOLDER
2018-04-06T20:32:00.7264430Z ##[debug]cmdToRun = rm -rf REDACTED_FOLDER
2018-04-06T20:32:01.5623712Z ##[debug]stderr = Failed to create shell
2018-04-06T20:32:01.5717192Z ##[error]Failed to create shell
2018-04-06T20:32:01.5752413Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Failed to create shell
2018-04-06T20:32:01.5775772Z ##[debug]stderr = 
2018-04-06T20:32:01.5786246Z 
2018-04-06T20:32:01.5810460Z ##[debug]code = 1, signal = undefined
2018-04-06T20:32:01.5840067Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2018-04-06T20:32:01.5875950Z ##[error]Command rm -rf REDACTED_FOLDER exited with code 1.
```

Here is a screenshot of my endpoint settings:

[Screenshot of Endpoint Auth settings screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAthb.png)

Comment: Can you show the screenshot for how you config the SSH endpoint? And what's the `REDACTED_PATH` and `REDACTED_FOLDER`, are they the variables or you just replace the real path and folder name here?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT - I've added a screenshot, and clarification on the redacted paths. I just replaced the actual ones for the sake of privacy- they are fully qualified in the actual input/output.

Comment: Do you have the permission to run rm -rf command?

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT - Yes, I am able to run rm -rf no problem when SSHing in manually using the same key